TextField keystrokes are not appearing when using a data class to hold the value and onValueChange parameters of the TextField
I'm trying to create multiple instances of the same TextField by iterating through them in a list rather than directly creating each instance. The problem is that none of the keystrokes are appearing in the TextField.
To start off I put the value and onValueChange parameters into a data class called "TextFieldClass.
data class TextFieldClass(
    var textValue: String,
    var onTextChange: (String) -> Unit,
    val label : String
)

I then made a list containing two instances of the "TextFieldClass" called "textFieldClasses"
val textFieldClasses = listOf(
    TextFieldClass(
        textValue = "",
        onTextChange = { newValue ->},
        label = "Text Field 1"
    ),
    TextFieldClass(
        textValue = "",
        onTextChange = { newValue ->},
        label = "Text Field 2"
    )

)
I then created a composable that contains the TextField UI called "TextFieldListItem" The value, onValueChange, and label parameters are passing into the constructor.
Composable
fun TextFieldListItem(
    text: String,
    onTextChange: (String) -> Unit,
    label: String
) {
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { onTextChange(it) },
        label = { Text(label) }
    )

}
I then created another composable to contain the "TextFieldListItem" and iterate through the "textFieldClasses" list called "TextFieldList" I'm sorry if using list too much is confusing.
@Composable
fun TextFieldList() {
    Column {
        textFieldClasses.forEach{ textFieldTests ->
            TextFieldListItem(
                text = textFieldTests.textValue,
                onTextChange = {textFieldTests.onTextChange(it)},
                label = textFieldTests.label
                )
        }
    }
}

And finally I put it all in the Main Activity.
However the problem still persists. The keystrokes are not appearing on the TextField. It just stays empty.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

The first problem here is that you basically declare an empty function here:
TextFieldClass( 
    textValue = "",
    onTextChange = { newValue ->},  // empty function doing nothing
    label = "Text Field 1"
)

Then you are assigning that empty function to the onTextChange of the TextField. So you would actually need something like this (this is also not going to work as I will explain below):
val onTextChange: (String) -> Unit = { textValue = it }  // ALSO NOT WORKING!

The second issue here is that you are using var for the properties in your TextFieldClass data class. Jetpack Compose cannot observe changes on mutable variables. You should change it to val and update properties of the data class using the copy function.
As the properties of your data class need to be immutable for Compose to detect changes, the approach of defining the onTextChange function in your TextFieldClass to update the textValue will not work. I'd suggest that you refactor your code.
First, make all the properties in your data class immutable and remove the onTextChange property:
data class TextFieldClass(
    val textValue: String,
    val label : String
)

Then, you need to declare your textFieldClasses in a way that Compose can detect when one item of the list was modified. You can achieve this by declaring a list using mutableStateListOf as follows:
val textFieldClasses = remember {
    mutableStateListOf(
        TextFieldClass(
            textValue = "",
            label = "Text Field 1"
        ),
        TextFieldClass(
            textValue = "",
            label = "Text Field 2"
        )
    )
}

Finally, once the value in a TextField changes, you need to update the data class instance in the textFieldClasses using the copy function:
textFieldClasses.forEachIndexed { position, textFieldTests ->
    TextFieldListItem(
        text = textFieldTests.textValue,
        onTextChange = { newText ->
            // update data class instance using copy and then update value in list
            textFieldClasses[position] = textFieldClasses[position].copy(textValue = newText)
        },
        label = textFieldTests.label
    )
}

Then, each TextField should be properly recomposed when you type something in there.
